# Determine the function defferentiable or not

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the fucntion

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\sin(\frac1x) & \text{for }x\ne0, \\
0 & \text{for }x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$
differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: classic example of a function that is continuous but not diferentiable ...

Comment: Apply the definition of the derivative as the limit of a difference quotient and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The function $x\mapsto \sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ doesn't have a limit at $0$ by considering the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{\frac\pi2+n\pi}\right)$

Comment: lol ... your hint is too complicated as usual to apply.

Comment: For this reason I called it hint and not answer! The OP should do some effort;-)

Comment: "as usual"!! Oh I'll check my previous hints and apparently I have a bad reputation on it lol

Comment: you consfused DonAntonio [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807850/discuss-the-uniform-convergence-of-function-fx/807860#807860) and now you confused me where is this hint applicable. It's a classic example I learnt when I was in High School. Probably it has duplicate somewhere.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with this hint, but it complicates things a little bit. All you need to show divergence at $x_0 =0$ is to see that $\sin t$ oscillates between -1 and 1 as $t \to \infty$

Comment: @Alex "oscillates between -1 and 1" isn't a rigorous argument and I think that to do mathematics we need sometimes a little bit of complication.

Comment: If the OP can't use the intuitive divergence of $\sin$ function, I guess this whole proof should be presented: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238997/prove-the-divergence-of-the-sequence-sinn-n-1-infty

Comment: I think that in this case (I can't say about *other* cases) the hint is as simple and direct as possibly wanted, and only requires substitution and some rather elementary trigonometric identity. +1

Answer (score 1):

**No:** By defination of derivatives;

$$f'(0)=lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}$$
$$=lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(h)}{h}$$
$$=lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{hsin(1/h)}{h}=lim_{h\to 0}sin(\dfrac 1 h)$$

It is enough to show that $lim_{x\to \infty}sin(x)$ does not exist.

if $x_n=\pi n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$, $lim_{n\to \infty}sin(x_n)=0$

if $x_n=(\pi/2)(4n-1)$, $lim_{n\to \infty}sin(x_n)=1$

Thus,  $lim_{x\to \infty}sin(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think in your examples of $\;x_n\;$ in the last lines you may want to take the reciprocals, e.g. $$x_n=\frac1{n\pi}\;\;\ldots etc.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: I wrote it there, "it is enough to show that $lim_{x\to \infty}sin(x)$ does not exist "

Comment: Oh, I see that now, @mesel. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome.