# Convergence in a Measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ the set of all $x\in[0,2\pi]$ at which $\{\sin (nx)\}$ converges.

This implies that $E$ is measurable?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, and $E=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ where $f$ is given by $f(t)=\limsup_n \sin(nt)-\liminf_n \sin(nt)$, it follows that $E$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown, that $\sin{nx}$ diverges for all irrational $x/\pi$ (We can easy deduce it from this question [Prove the divergence of the sequence $\left\{ \sin(n) \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238997/prove-the-divergence-of-the-sequence-sinn-n-1-infty), Bruno Joyal's answer [with the link to equidistribution]). Hence, even without checking for which  $x$ it converges, we can say that $E$ is measurable, because it is countable.

Comment: Any reference for $\sin nx$ diverges for irrational $x$?;thanks.

Comment: @user126033 You are right.There should be $x/\pi$. Corrected.