# $\lim_{n\to\infty} z^n - z^{2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Exactly what it says on the tin.

Find for what values of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ does this limit exist:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} z^n - z^{2n}$$

The cases when $|z|\not = 1$ are fairly simple, but I am struggling with $|z|=1$.

My intuition and wolfram alpha tell me that it diverges if $z\not = 1$, but I cannot formalize the argument.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238997/prove-the-divergence-of-the-sequence-left-sinn-right-n-1-infty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Well, $z^n - z^{2n}$  has a limit as $n$ goes to $+ \infty$ if and only if (**why?**) $\mathfrak{Re}(z^n - z^{2n})$ and $\mathfrak{Im}(z^n - z^{2n})$ have both a limit as $n$ goes to $+ \infty$. If $|z| = 1$, then $z = e^{i\theta}$. Therefore, study the limit of $x_n =\cos(\theta n)- \cos(2\theta n)$ and $y_n = \sin(\theta n)- \sin(2\theta n)$ as $n$ goes to $+ \infty$ given the value of $\theta$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind.

If we suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} z^n - z^{2n}=\lambda$ then it should happen that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (z^n - z^{2n}) - (z^{n+1} - z^{2n+2}) = 0$.

But 
$$
(z^n - z^{2n}) - (z^{n+1} - z^{2n+2}) = z^n (1-z) (1-z^{2n}(1+z)
$$
taking the module, $|z^n (1-z) (1-z^{2n}(1+z)|> |1-z|(|2|+|z|) > 0$ (since $z\not=1$), so contradiction and GG.